# Unable to load from AssetManifest.json

Tags: flutter

Need to load assets using String

```
 Future<void> uploadData() async {
    final assetsManifest = await DefaultAssetBundle.of(Get.context!)
        .loadString('AssetManifest.json');
    final assets = json.decode(assetsManifest).keys;

    final manifestContent = await DefaultAssetBundle.of(Get.context!)
        .loadString("AssetManifest.json");
    final Map<String, dynamic> manifestMap = json.decode(manifestContent);
    final papersInAssets = manifestMap.keys
        .where((path) =>
            path.startsWith("assets/DB/paper") && path.contains(".json"))
        .toList();
    print(papersInAssets);
  }
```

Project structure
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GqfA8.png)

This is the output
expected to print a list of assets

```
estarted application in 2,750ms.
[GETX] Instance "DataUploader" has been created
[GETX] Instance "DataUploader" has been initialized
[GETX] Instance "GetMaterialController" has been created
[GETX] Instance "GetMaterialController" has been initialized
I/flutter (12563): []
```

Comment: What is the error you are getting?

Comment: I am getting an empty list

Comment: can you trying printing list of keys [manifestMap.keys] to see if there is any value there

Comment: Restarted application in 2,740ms.
[GETX] Instance "DataUploader" has been created
[GETX] Instance "DataUploader" has been initialized
[GETX] Instance "GetMaterialController" has been created
[GETX] Instance "GetMaterialController" has been initialized
I/flutter (12563): (packages/cupertino_icons/assets/CupertinoIcons.ttf)

Comment: you can edit question to put output. As of now, it returns only ttf result hence your json filter is empty.

Comment: could you elaborate?